Python code to export NIfTI volume slices produces brightness-incoherent images
I am a beginner with MRI and Python.
I am trying to export slice images from a .nii.gz file.
I had ChatGPT write down this sample code for me. The code stores images of slices on the three planes as desired.
The issue I cannot fix is that different .nii.gz files result in slice images with different and incoherent levels of brightness.
Brightness-coherent set of slice images
Brightness-incoherent set of slice images #1
Brightness-incoherent set of slice images #2
These directory screenshots show how each image has a different brightness level. Some .nii.gz files provide images with correct and coherent brightness among all slices. Other don't.
This is the code I got from ChatGTP:
import nibabel as nib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np

def save_slices(volume, plane_name, axis, output_dir):
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
for i in range(volume.shape[axis]):
if axis == 0:
slice_img = volume[i, :, :]
elif axis == 1:
slice_img = volume[:, i, :]
elif axis == 2:
slice_img = volume[:, :, i]

        # Normalize the slice image
        slice_img = (slice_img - np.min(slice_img)) / (np.max(slice_img) - np.min(slice_img)) * 255
        slice_img = slice_img.astype(np.uint8)
    
        plt.imshow(slice_img.T, cmap='gray', origin='lower')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.savefig(os.path.join(output_dir, f"{plane_name}_slice_{i:03d}.png"), bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)
        plt.close()

# Load the NIfTI file

nifti_file = '../dataset/raw/HUMAN/UCSF-PDGM-v3/UCSF-PDGM-0005_nifti/UCSF-PDGM-0005_DTI_eddy_L2.nii.gz'
nifti_img = nib.load(nifti_file)
volume = nifti_img.get_fdata()

# Define output directories

output_dirs = {
'axial': 'output/axial',
'coronal': 'output/coronal',
'sagittal': 'output/sagittal'
}

# Save slices for each plane

save_slices(volume, 'axial', 2, output_dirs['axial'])
save_slices(volume, 'coronal', 1, output_dirs['coronal'])
save_slices(volume, 'sagittal', 0, output_dirs['sagittal'])

What's the issue?
Thanks everyone for the help!

Found the answer.
First, I did not take the global volume minimum, but the slice minimum.
Secondly, some scans may have extremely dark outliers (i.e. artefacts from rapid acquisition).
These outliers nullify the effect of subtracting the global minimum from the slice.
Subtracting a percentile-based minimum (i.e. 0.05) instead of the absolute minimum correctly restores the brightness of the whole set of slice images.

Even better would be to use the same values for all images in your directory (not just of 1 volume), then you can also compare between volumes.

@alle_meije, true indeed. Thank you for sharing.
